# How can i import or set a version to my .apk file for recognize upgrading in AppMarkets

Tags: android

i have a question:
How can i import or set a version to my .apk file for recognize upgrading in AppMarkets?
have a good time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find information on versioning your app on this [site](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/versioning.html).

You should declare the version of your app in the manifest file. If it's higher than the one on the android device, it will recognize it as an updated version of your app. This version should be an integer value.

I'm talking about the version code, the versionName is your own choice. the versionCode has to be the integer and incrementing every time you launch an updated version of your app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.package.name"
  android:versionCode="2"
  android:versionName="1.1">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: I'd just like to add that the android market will display your versionName value as the version of your app, and with each new version that you release you should increase versionCode by 1.